# pass array to spring controller via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to ajax. I found many similar answer but I can't figure out why my request syntactically incorrect. 
Here is my code:
ajax code:

```
$(".f-remove-button").click(function(){
            console.log("remove-clicked");
             var userIds = [];
            $.each($("input[name='userIds']:checked"),
            function(){
                userIds.push($(this).val());
            });
            console.log(userIds);
            var url = "/clubtivity/user/remove-contacts"
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:url,
                dataType:"json",
                data:{"userIds":userIds},
                success:function(response){

                }
            });

        });
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove-contacts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Long[] removeConnections(@RequestParam(value="userIds") String[] userIds, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    //some code
    return null;
}
```

Please help me to figure out my mistake. sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 0):

RequestParam is incorrect, you should use @RequestBody instead.
Judging from high level, you should create a POJO object that contain the array.

```
public class POJO {

    private String[] userIds;

    public POJO() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the userIds
     */
    public String[] getUserIds() {
        return userIds;
    }

    /**
     * @param userIds the userIds to set
     */
    public void setUserIds(String[] userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
    }
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove-contacts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Long[] removeConnections(@RequestBody POJO pojo, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        //some code
        return null;
    }
```